# How to only pull last 24 hours logs from Slack accesslogs API?

Tags: java, algorithm, api, slack, slack-api

**API reference**: https://api.slack.com/methods/team.accessLogs

**Overview:**
Slack Access logs API does not have 'start date' parameter, it only has 'before' date parameter. Each access log entry in the response has date_first and date_last fields. date_first is the first time user accessed slack using the combination of IP address and user agent and date_last is the last time the user accessed slack using that same combination. The logs in response are sorted in reverse chronological order on date_first. Pagination is by 1000 records per page.

**My use-case:**
I want to get all the access logs which have date_last in the last 24 hours. Once I get all the logs with date_last that belong to the last 24 hours, I want to stop the execution for requesting more data from slack

**Issue:**
Since the logs in the response are sorted based on date_first, I don't know where to stop my request call because if I stop when I reach date_first for a log beyond 24 hours, I might lose data beyond that record for which date_last might be within last 24 hours which is possible as a log might have date_first not within 24 hours but still have date_last within 24 hours. If I stop when I find date_last greater than 24 hours, I will lose data after it which might have date_last within 24 hours which is possible as the logs are not sorted based on date_last.

**Example of accesslogs API response**:

```
{
"ok": true,
"logins": [
    {
        "user_id": "U45678",
        "username": "alice",
        "date_first": 1422922864,
        "date_last": 1422922864,
        "count": 1,
        "ip": "127.0.0.1",
        "user_agent": "SlackWeb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.35 Safari/537.36",
        "isp": "BigCo ISP",
        "country": "US",
        "region": "CA"
    },
    {
        "user_id": "U12345",
        "username": "white_rabbit",
        "date_first": 1422922493,
        "date_last": 1422922493,
        "count": 1,
        "ip": "127.0.0.1",
        "user_agent": "SlackWeb Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B466 Safari/600.1.4",
        "isp": "BigCo ISP",
        "country": "US",
        "region": "CA"
    }
],
"paging": {
    "count": 100,
    "total": 2,
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 1
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Each entry in the response to `team.accessLogs` corresponds to a collection of actions -- for a user, user agent and ip address -- aggregated by 2 hour blocks.

That means that even if a user keeps the same user agent and ip address, you'll see a new entry roughly every two hours. For that reason, in order to get all the data for the last 24 hours, you can go back as far as 24 + 2 hours using `date_first` and that will make sure that you have everything within the 24 hour range.